# How to get an image to fill a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an auto slideshow and I want to get all images to fill to the div horizontally and vertically. At the moment, they are all different sizes and they overflow outside of the div; they seem to ignore the sizes I've given them. When it's working I would like to place it on my website below a navigation bar and take up around half of the page. **The h1 tag is also supposed to be under the images but it is underneath the images so not sure what's happening there.** I've never tried anything like this before so any help is greatly appreciated! It's probably something simple I've missed somewhere.

I have attached a Codepen to show the problem: https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/JpKvOq

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pageContainer">
  <div id="slideshowContainer">
    <div class="fadein">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/6986083-waterfall-images_Mc3SaMS.jpg">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/road-dawn-mountains-sky.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Testing</h1>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#pageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#slideshowContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.fadein {
  position: relative;
}

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {


$(".fadein img:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".fadein :first-child")
      .fadeOut()
      .next("img")
      .fadeIn()
      .end()
      .appendTo(".fadein");
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: A few things. First, try thinking about moving the fadein animation to CSS instead of jQuery. MUCH faster and smoother (using `transition` on the `opacity` rule). Second, try switching the backgrounds to `background-image` css rule, having `background-size` set to `cover`. This will fit the bg image to its container. Third, the images cover your title because of the `position: absolute` rule.

Comment: I tried using css transitions but they seemed to have a "popping" or "explosion" style fading to them. I was after a cross fade, which jquery seems to achieve.

Comment: The best way to achieve this, is by making all images hidden using `opacity: 0` css rule, and then add a class using JS timeout (like the one you did) that overrides that rule and set `opacity: 1`. By setting the `transition` on those elements to either `opacity 0.5s` or `all 0.5s`, you'll get a smoother result, at the fraction of the cost (in cpu power).

Comment: Is it possible you could edit my codepen? I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that. It's the first time I've ever tried anything like this before. https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/JpKvOq

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQExVP

Comment: Oooh, okay, that makes sense. Is it possible to get the "testing" to move below the images? That's where my other page content will be.

Comment: I was just showing you how to use CSS for the fade in animation. It's not a copy paste solution for production...

Comment: Okay :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is giving `.fadein img` absolute positioning in a 100% width `#slideshowContainer`. You need to specify the container size and set to `overflow: hidden;`

Replace in your CSS:

```
#slideshowContainer {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fadein img {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well, thank you! The thing with overflow: hidden is it will show mostly the top of the image and cut some of the bottom off. Is it possible to get the image to center vertically, cutting a little off top and bottom?

Comment: Again, try looking at `background-size: cover`. I truly think this is what you are after: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: As @Narxx suggests, you can control the positioning of images better when applied to `<div>` backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

That seem to resolve your issue:

```
.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

And for the H1 text:

```
h1{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```